# Cannot edit comment twice in a row without a page reload

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-edits

I cannot edit a comment twice without reloading the page. Steps to reproduce:

1. Post a comment
2. Click "edit", make a change, save.
3. Click "edit" again.

Expected result: The edit box appears to edit the comment

Actual result: Nothing happens at all.

I'm using Safari Version 5.1 (7534.48.3) on Mac OS X 10.7; I have not yet tested other browsers.

[image: FHC Goodness]

Comment: Initial Test Comment. Edit #1.

Comment: Confirmed repro, Chrome Stable, Win7.

Comment: This happens only on meta. I cannot reproduce it on [so] or the SE sites (checked on 2 sites).

Comment: We're looking at this.

Comment: Confirmed on StackOverflow, using Chrome 14.0.835.202 m

Comment: Confirmed on both SO and MSO, using Chrome 14 / Ubuntu.

Comment: Confirmed, Firefox 7.0.1

Comment: I've been experiencing this problem since yesterday, I think. (Chrome 15.0.874.92 beta-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally my fault. When moving over the refactored comment JavaScript from my little sandbox into the main JS files, I missed an important line. This caused some operations (including "add a textarea for editing") to happen on old DOM elements that aren't in the document anymore.

So somewhere in the mind of your browser, the edit box was actually there. Not that that's helpful.

Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense to me. And it works now! Thanks!